# Sword and Sworcery segfaults, how can I reinstall it?

Tags: games, segmentation-fault

I've just bought, installed Sword and Sworcery via the Software Centre.

When I run it, the screen goes black, the cursor changes and then all reverts back to normal.

I found the executable that matches the menu item.

```
/bin/sh /opt/swordandsworcery/run.sh
```

When I run it from the console:

```
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

My setup:

```
Linux jem-doxie 3.2.0-24-generic #39-Ubuntu SMP Mon May 21 16:52:17 UTC 2012 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

Where to from here? Refund? Or can I do something?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I was able to get this working by doing the following:

- Uninstall from the terminal `sudo apt-get remove swordandsworcery-bin`
- Download the deb from the link in the email "Your Humble Bundle order" (received after purchasing the humble bundle)
- Install the deb from the terminal (it failed from the software centre) with `sudo dpkg -i swordandsworcery_1.00-1_amd64.deb`

Note, I replaced v1.56 with v1.00 - that may be why it now works.

Comment: did you have problems with dependencies when installing like this?

Comment: ran apt-get install -f to add 150MB of dependencies and works OK now :)

Answer (score 1):

I have the same issue and contacted the developers (Capybara Games). They've been very responsive and pointed me to this page. Hopefully, they can get it sorted for the version in the Ubuntu Software Centre so that users don't have to go fiddling with installing a .deb.

By the way, you can find the logs here, they may have a hint as to what's going wrong:

```
~/.capy/SwordAndSworcery/log.txt
```

Answer (score 1):

I have fixed this problem for several people, and the solution seems to be:

```
sudo apt-get install libpulse0:i386
```

I hope this is useful.

Answer (score 1):

I know this is an old thread, but I found a fix, at least on my system. I was having the same issue, on Ubuntu 12.10 64-bit with dual monitors, even after I turned one of them off. I went into /opt/swordandsworcery/run.sh and uncommented the SDL line. That got me to the segfault issue. Then I went into ~/.capy/SwordAndSworcery/config.txt and found that the width was set to 3840, which is double my single-monitor resolution (or the total resolution when both monitors are on). Switched that to 1920 and everything loaded fine after that.